# How to deal with problems in commands resulted from a version update of R?

Tags: r, rgdal

I am a neophyte of R. Recently, I have unconsciously updated R on my computer from 4.0.2 to 4.0.3. After I substituted successfully the older one with 4.0.3 and installed all related packages again, I eventually realized that my commands written in the 4.0.2 version do not work in the 4.0.3 environment. (My nemesis must be familiar to you all, but, unfortunately, I found out the truth too lately) Here are my problems. First, if commands are not compatible between versions, which one would be the cause, the updated package or the updated R? Second, how and where can I/do you modify codes for an upgrade?

What I have been doing is to read a shapefile of Taiwan for maps. And here are the codes that are incompatible, which are all written in R 4.0.2 format:

```
Shapefile <- readOGR(dsn = "directory", layer = "Popn_TWN2")

### Warning message:
In OGRSpatialRef(dsn, layer, morphFromESRI = morphFromESRI, dumpSRS = dumpSRS,  :
  Discarded datum Taiwan_Datum_1997 in CRS definition: +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=121 +k=0.9999 +x_0=250000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

The second one: ("table" is a data frame with geographical data and is going to be transformed into the same coordinate system as Shapefile above)

```
assign("table", spTransform(tableData, CRS("+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=121 +k=0.9999 +x_0=250000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs")))

### Warning message:
In showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO", prefer_proj = prefer_proj) :
  Discarded datum Unknown based on GRS80 ellipsoid in CRS definition
```

And the last one, which intends to count the number of overlaps of table on Shapefile:

```
assign("over", table(over(table, Shapefile)$TOWN))

### Error in .local(x, y, returnList, fn, ...) : 
  identicalCRS(x, y) is not TRUE
```

So, what I am looking for is the identification of bugs among the commands and possible solutions. Please tell me if my description is insufficient.

Comment: It looks like every warning or error is related to `readOGR` misinterpreting the CRS of the shapefile. This is a change in the `rgdal` package, not R itself, but you can also check the changelog between R versions at [R News](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html) to learn more about what changes between versions.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  I think you are confusing an _upgrade of R_ (likely to have little side effect by itself) with _an upgrade of all packages you had installed_ as the issue here is clearly with one of the packages.  Which you could have upgraded without upgrading R, in short I think you have a vanilla bug in one package and should re-focus your question on that.

Comment: An update to this question. I have solved the issue (especially the last one) by transforming the proj4string of both table and Shapefile, which makes the two files ready for over-method. [Reference](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224265/error-identicalcrsx-y-is-not-true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent this from happening when you update R you can use the groundhog package which makes calls to load R package be version specific (so use groundhog.library(,) instead of library()

For example,

```
library('grounhdog')
groundhog.library('rgdal', '2020-10-11')
```

will always load the same version of 'rgdal', the one that was current on 2020-10-11, even as you install a new version of R. You can of course update 'rgdal' by simply changing the date used to load it in the groundhog.library() command. If you realize an update breaks your code, you can just go back to the previous version by keeping the old date, or use groundhog to find the source of the problem and update your code accordingly.

Read more at http://groundhogr.com